# Is there a way to have ListView to be on the right side of the screen?

Tags: android-studio

I am making an app (for homework) that displays the subject's grades and what the teacher has to say about the student as a String, but but I need the ListView to be on the right hand side of the screen (it needs to support a language from right to left, unlike English left to right) and I couldn't find a way to do it

I tried using layout_gravity="right"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/subjectLW">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I expected the text inside the ListView stick to the right hand side of the screen but instead nothing happens, there is probably a way of making it happen and I don't know how to do it

Update:
Right now I used android:layout_gravity="end" instead of android:layout_gravity="right" to make the text stick to the right side of the ListView, but I would like the ListView itself to be on the right side of the screen, refer to the pictures below, still clueless on how to do it.

Second Update:
Solution was found, instead of using layout_gravity="right" ListView needed textAlignment="center" and then it updates itself to the corresponding type of language, if it is left-right it will stick to the right size, and if it is right-left it will stick to the right side of the screen.

[The Screens current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9nWT.png)

[How I need it to look like (done with the magic of MS Paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2xOF.png)

Comment: You want the text to be aligned to the right-hand side of your listview?

Comment: Can you please post the `layout` you are implementing inside the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set layout_gravity="end" in your `ListView` item view `TextView`.

Comment: It improved how the text looks like but but the ListView itself is still at the left hand side of the screen. Any Idea on how to get it to the right side?

Comment: Edit your answer with your `ListView` item `.xml` file.

Comment: <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/subjectLW">

    </ListView>

uhh there you go, sorry

Comment: Edit you original question. This is `ListView` `.xml` and I told You to post here your `ListView` item `.xml`